# How to left justify the title page of Appendix in the `report` class?

Tags: appendices, report, appendix

I have looked into the documentation of `appendix`, and I have not been able to find any directions about how to format the Appendix title page.

Currently, it displays "Appendix" in the center of the page. I want to left-justify it, like all the other titles in `report`, including the References title page.

Is there a way to do this?

I think the relevant code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{appendices}
```

The result is a centered title page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal example code reproducing the problem?

Comment: The command \appendix places the appendix title. I do not know how to format the title.

Comment: We need to have  a minimal code, even if you don't format it as you wish, to know  your document class, which (related) packages you load, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You have some work to do. Here is an MWE that produces a left justified Appendix page title instead of a centered one.

```
 % appendixpageprob2.tex  SE 511071 left justify appendices title

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
  \clear@ppage
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
  \null\vfil
  \markboth{}{}%
  {%centering  % comment this out to get non-centered title
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \Huge \bfseries \appendixname\par}%
  \if@dotoc@pp
    \addappheadtotoc
  \fi
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Another}
\lipsum[2]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

It would have been most helpful if you had taken the effort to provide an MWE (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that showed your problem. As it was I had to spend extra effort and time inventing what I thought was your problem. I hope I got it right, but who can tell? GOM